# Google play store alpha and beta tracks

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have an application in the play store and I want to set up a  beta track and an alpha track. In short, the beta track is intended to be open so people can opt-in anytime, while the alpha track is intended for select invitations only.

One of the problems that I'm having is that the beta-track seems to be recognized on my phone but the alpha track weirdly is not. The alpha track has a higher release version than the beta track has, so I am expecting the play store to show list the version of the alpha track (on my personal devices) however it quite persistently keeps  showing the version of the beta track.

Anybody know what this is about? Am I using the playstore wrong is there something else I should enable first?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding for the play store is a bit different. Its better to look at the channels as below:

1. Alpha Track as Closed Track. Only registered users can install the app in this track.
2. Beta Track is Open Track. Everyone who has opted for Beta testing can install the app.
3. Production Track is your main track. Play store will use this to distribute your app to your end users.

To register your users for the Closed Track(Alpha), go to the Alpha track and add a list of users by their emails who can download app through this channel. My company uses Developers who can access the Closed track, so simply add all the developer's emails in that list and you are good to go.
[image]

Comment: I fail to see how I have a misunderstanding. What you describe is exactly the same setup that I have. Production for general public, Open beta so people can opt-in, and alpha as a closed track. 

The opt-in urls for beta and alpa are exactly the same, I opted myself in before to "become" a tester, but yet when I introduced the alpha track my phone doesn't get to see the version that was released to alpha.

Comment: What i should have said instead is instead of alpha or beta, prefer saying open or closed. To solve the open closed problem, try creating two different lists and have a different test account for alpha. For some reasons beta is always used.

Comment: When you have an open beta track, you get an opt-in url where users can subscribe. When I create a closed alpha track, you get the /same/ opt-in url as beta track, but you can add email addresses...

So how am I supposed to have two different lists when clearly when i want my device to opt-in for alpha, automatically opt-in for beta because they use the same uri?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to register alpha testing group for your app. If you register both alpha and beta testing groups, your project's version code is important. You are going to see the biggest version code number app in your phone alpha, beta or production. For example you have an apk in beta with version code 3 and you have an apk with version code 4 in alpha, you should see alpha version available on google play.I mean that the important thing is version code of your app.

Comment: That's exactly why I am posting my question because I am part of both the beta and the alpha track, but my phone only lists the beta track e.g. beta is 2.0.14 and alpha is 2.0.15. From the play store I see the version 2.0.14 is listed. The opt-in urls for both alpha and beta are exactly the same thing, so I don't know why do I not see my alpha??

Comment: Are you sure about your version code ? Not version number. Version code in build gradle

Comment: I could have a closer look at it, but I am changing the version number at least that allows play store to detect which apk's to deactivate and which ones to activate. If there's also something about a version code that needs changing.... none of the ui ever hinted or explained that.